# Why keyword `match` in Python 3.10 can be as a variable or function name?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, keyword, python-3.10

I don't fully understand why the keyword `match` can be used as a variable or function name, unlike other keywords `if`, `while`, etc.?

```py
>>> match "abc":
...     case "abc":
...         print('Hello!')
...     
Hello!
>>> from re import match
>>> match('A', 'A Something A')
<re.Match object; span=(0, 1), match='A'>
>>> match = '????'
>>> match
'????'
>>> case = 'something'
>>> case
'something'
```

Comment: Have you read [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#backwards-compatibility)'s section on backwards compatibility?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image. 
[Why do we hate screenshots so much?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/)

Comment: Think about this: how much existing code would break if it couldn't?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per [PEP 622](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#backwards-compatibility), `match` and `case` are being added as ["soft keywords"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65800344/what-are-soft-keywords), so they will remain valid identifiers:

> This PEP is fully backwards compatible: the `match` and `case` keywords are proposed to be (and stay!) soft keywords, so their use as variable, function, class, module or attribute names is not impeded at all.